# Charindex, Getting specific data from a string

Tags: sql-server-2012, t-sql

Hello I am very new to charindex and have tried to create a query that would extract my needed information but am running into an error.  I searched for similar problems on stackexchange as well as a few other sites and it seems I am still unable to fully grasp the concept to get what I need.

My biggest issue is the data that I have in the column is not in any set pattern.  I found a stackexchange question that answered this but my setup is a bit different.  Here are a few examples from column descr and table facility:

```
ID | Descr |
21 | Playhouse, Virginia Series, 98 Stage, PSDD, House|
35 | Playhouse, Virginia Series, 111 Stage, Inconel|
53 | Playhouse, FX Series, 125 Stage, House F31|
76 | FX Series, 134 Stage, F31, Onconel|
```

A bit more information.  There should always be a comma before the number I am looking for.  I have found one case out of thousands that this isn't the case, but to make this easier we will assume it always has a leading comma and space.  The number I am looking for can be either two or three digits.  It is also always followed by a space and the word stage.

Here is what I attemped but received and error:
select

```
with cterecords(descr, position) as
(
    select
        descr, charindex(',', descr) position
        from facility
)
    select
        substring(descr, position +1,
        charindex('stage', descr,position) - position -1)
    from cterecords;
```

I am receiving this error:
Msg 537, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

But if I get through the error, I am not sure if I have the query written to get exactly what I want.

Here is SQL Fiddle with test data: [SQL Fiddle Example Data](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5c8f3)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use `charIndex` and `patIndex` to resolve it.

```
CASE WHEN PatIndex('%, [0-9][0-9]% Stage%',Descr) > 0 
    AND LEN(SUBSTRING(Descr,1,CharIndex(' Stage', Descr)-1))>=3
    THEN RIGHT(SUBSTRING(Descr,1,CharIndex(' Stage', Descr)-1),3) 
    ELSE NULL END
    AS NewNo,   
CASE WHEN PatIndex('%, [0-9][0-9]% Stage%',Descr) > 0 
    AND LEN(SUBSTRING(Descr,1,CharIndex(' Stage', Descr)-1))>=3
    THEN SUBSTRING(Descr, PatIndex('%, [0-9][0-9]% Stage%',Descr)+2,3)
    ELSE NULL END
    AS NewNo2
```

With the output:

```
NewNo NewNo2
----- ------
 98   98 
111   111
125   125
134   134
```

Some explanation on it:
I used to `CharIndex(' Stage', Descr)`to find the position when starts `' Stage'`.
Then I use `SUBSTRING(Descr,1,CharIndex(' Stage', Descr)-1)` to cut the text so that your number will be in the right part. (like this :`Playhouse, Virginia Series, 98`).Then you can use different technique (`right`,another `charIndex`,`reverse`) to obtain the Number.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that, even if there is no comma, at least a space character is always there before the sought number (when it is not at the beginning of `Descr`), here is what you could do:

1. Find the position of `' Stage'`:

   ```
   CHARINDEX(' Stage', Descr)
   ```
2. Cut the string at that position.

   ```
   STUFF(Descr, CHARINDEX(...), 999999999, '')
   ```

   If `CHARINDEX` finds nothing, it returns 0. When 0 is specified as the second parameter of `STUFF`, the result will be NULL, which should make sense, I assume.
3. Take the three rightmost characters from the remaining string.

   ```
   RIGHT(STUFF(...), 3)
   ```

   If the number is two digits, you will probably get a space character at the beginning, which, in my estimation, should be fine, as the result will still be easily convertible to a numeric type (if that is the ultimate goal).

   If the number is two digits and the `nn Stage` item is at the beginning of `Descr`, you will actually get only the two digits, without any space character, which should be even better.

So, putting everything together, this is the complete expression:

```
RIGHT(STUFF(Descr, CHARINDEX(' Stage', Descr), 999999999, ''), 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example.

There is a very common function that gets used in SQL databases called *fnSplit*. It's not native, but I have seen it added to databases many times. It's a table-valued function that takes a string and returns a table (splitting the string on some delimiter).

The code for the function is below:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnSplit](
    @sInputList NVARCHAR(MAX) -- List of delimited items
  , @sDelimiter NVARCHAR(8) = ',' -- delimiter that separates items
) RETURNS @List TABLE (item NVARCHAR(MAX))
BEGIN
DECLARE @sItem VARCHAR(8000)
WHILE CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter,@sInputList,0) <> 0
 BEGIN
 SELECT
    @sItem=RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@sInputList,1,CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter,@sInputList,0)-1))),
@sInputList=RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@sInputList,CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter,@sInputList,0)+LEN(@sDelimiter),LEN(@sInputList))))

 IF LEN(@sItem) > 0
  INSERT INTO @List SELECT @sItem
 END

IF LEN(@sInputList) > 0
 INSERT INTO @List SELECT @sInputList -- Put the last item in
RETURN
END
```

**NOTE:** I did not write *fnSplit*, the credit for that goes to [deeptideshpande here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/4126a010-6885-4eb0-b79c-c798c90edb85/how-to-split-comma-delimited-string%20%22here').

Once you have that function, your problem is easy; just split the text on space and then just look for numbers:

```
DECLARE @Data TABLE (ID INT,Descr NVARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT INTO @Data
VALUES
(21,'Playhouse, Virginia Series, 98 Stage, PSDD, House'),
(35,'Playhouse, Virginia Series, 111 Stage, Inconel'),
(53,'Playhouse, FX Series, 125 Stage, House F31'),
(76,'FX Series, 134 Stage, F31, Onconel')

SELECT      *
FROM        @Data AS D
OUTER APPLY dbo.fnSplit(D.Descr,' ') AS S
WHERE       ISNUMERIC(S.item) = 1
```